# Is it adequate UX to ask for a URL, cloud hosted or otherwise, for images in the Django admin interface?

Tags: image, urls, cloud

I'm working on a Django project with data entry presently handled by the Django admin interface. I intend to provide my own interface as an adaptation of the Django admin interface concept to provide finer-grained control.

Some years ago, it would have been bad UX to ask a nontechnical administrator, "Upload a photograph to the cloud and paste the URL here." Now cloud storage is mainstream and I'd expect more people would make sense of a request to upload to cloud and paste in the image's URL.

Is it appropriate UX-wise, perhaps with explanation, to ask people who want to display images to do so by uploading to a cloud service and providing a cloud-hosted URL?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure why you have to specify "upload an image and add link here..." Just clearly state: "Link to your image." What might be helpful is showing if the link works immediately by loading a "preview" image right next to the link.

Comment: I'd try and sample your audience, as that's the only way you'll know for sure. Everything else is speculation. Sometimes users are [shockingly inexperienced with computers](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/computer-skill-levels/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wholly depends on your intended audience. "Non-technical" is subjective, so it is probably wise to do some level of research on your intended audience before committing to an interface design.

Some thoughts:
 1. Add links to the most popular services, for convenience.
 2. Think about linking to a short tutorial on how to find the public URL.

Example:

[image: Example]

Edit: I want to add that the user experience goes both ways. The intended *viewer* may not be able to view uploaded images. They might have an adblocker enabled, or sit behind a corporate firewall that blocks certain less popular file hosts. Imgur, for example, is blocked on quite a few corporate networks. Of course, user-linked files may also be prone to vulnerabilities or [contain exploits](https://www.virusbulletin.com/virusbulletin/2016/04/how-it-works-steganography-hides-malware-image-files/). Therefore, it may be wise to limit the domains you accept images from, and for images to be run through a scan before being authorized for public display. A good option is to use the [VirusTotal API](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/) for scanning the URLs submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna provide popular cloud platform options and only ask them to choose the one they use and enter a filename. If they don't use any of those popular cloud platforms, ask them to provide a link.

If they choose one of those popular platforms, you will just prepend the filename with a path to the chosen cloud platform's image directory.

You might also want to ping the link and verify that it returns a Content-Type: image/jpg|png|gif, that would be nice for validation.